# Cos'è una "risata a frullo"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo  Calvino, ho letto questa frase:

> Dietro di loro s'udì il riso di Donna Viola, una delle sue **risate a frullo**.

Ho cercato il termine "frullo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non capisco cos'è una "risata a frullo". Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [questa edizione de *Il barone rampante*](https://books.google.it/books?id=-dU0BF_Nw_MC&pg=PT192&lpg=PT192&dq=risata%20a%20frullo%20il%20barone%20rampante&source=bl&ots=C9QEPV79qb&sig=zEaAQHf1iCGrOnflQLvaAVUm3R0&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl-NP6idjaAhWRLlAKHT6-AwcQ6AEIQDAI#v=onepage&q=risata%20a%20frullo%20il%20barone%20rampante&f=false) ho trovato:

> Dalla gola di Donna Viola si levò una risata leggera come un frullo
>   d'ali.

Questo passaggio penso spieghi il significato di risata a frullo.

Inoltre in [*Versants*, Edizioni 47-50](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=OaYLAQAAMAAJ&dq=barone%20rampante%20risata%20frullo%20ali&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=risata%20frullo%20ali) si può leggere:

> Bionda, vestita di azzurro, talora procedente a zig-zag è la bambina
>   Viola (poi Donna Viola) nel Barone rampante (cfr. RR I 563, 590, 706).
>   Ha una risata tutta sua, riconoscibile, «a frullo», «leggera come un
>   frullo d'ali» (RR I 729 e 727).